# AngularJs - how to use function variable outside controller of promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

service.js

```
.factory('tableService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        getTable: function() {
            return $http.get("data/timesheet.json");
        }
    }
}])
```

controller.js

```
.controller('tableCtrl', function($filter, $sce, ngTableParams, tableService) {

    var promise = tableService.getTable();

    promise.then(
         function(payload) {                    
            data = JSON.stringify(payload.data);
            alert(data);
        },
        function(errorPayload) {
            $log.error('failure loading movie', errorPayload);
        });

            //Editable
    this.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10           // count per page
        }, {
            total:data.length, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
})
```

I am very new to AngularJs. The issue is that am not getting JSON file data in my table. Here I used alert to check whether data is coming from JSON file or not and it's working but somehow getting empty table as data is not being displayed in my table. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: assign the data to a scope variable

Comment: I did it but it was not working @Sajeetharan

Comment: @Sajeetharan can I do it without scope variable?

Comment: Probably you forget to declare `data`, please declare `data` like `var data`; below `var promise = tableService.getTable()`;

Answer (score 0):

You need to either have a scope variable or a controller variable and assign the fetched data to it. Below is a controller variable solution:

```
.controller('tableCtrl', function($filter, $sce, ngTableParams, tableService) {
        var self = this;
        var promise = tableService.getTable();
        self.tableData = [];
        promise.then(
            function(payload) { 

                data = JSON.stringify(payload.data);
                alert(data);
                self.tableData = data;
            },
            function(errorPayload) {
              $log.error('failure loading movie', errorPayload);
            });

        self.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10           // count per page
        }, {
            total: self.tableData.length, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                $defer.resolve(total:tableData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
    })
```

**EDIT**: Answer below was posted before OP's edits

You are referring to the `data` property of `$scope`:

```
total:$scope.data.length
```

but you aren't assigning it anywhere.
You should update your promise callback:

```
function(payload) {     
    data = JSON.stringify(payload.data);
    alert(data);
    $scope.data = data;
}
```

Comment: when I use console.log(tableData) outside promise function am getting 0 length array

Comment: Added `self` reference, check if this changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code, you should use $scope when you are binding data to the view,

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {
myService.getJSON().then(function(data){
            $scope.myData =data;
            console.log(data);
 });

});


app.service('myService', function($http) {
  this.getJSON = function() {
    return $http.get('test.json').then(function(data) {
      return data.data.items;
    });
  };
});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/BJ7wozMyTkLDZGVcwcyz?p=preview)**

Comment: $scope variable is not working for me as I need to defer data in controller

Comment: You should have , look at the sample above